# Selenium Python: How to wait until an element finish changing the text before reading the value using?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to read the value of a text from a page using Selenium Python. The element is always visible and then goes invisible and then becomes visible and the text value changes rapidly until it reaches the final value. I think it is using some form of javascript to get the value before displaying the final value.

The page is https://www.junglescout.com/estimator/

I am trying to get the result of the estimate from the element js-magic-result.

I'm able to use Selenium to fill the three forms and click the 'calculates sales' button

I am using the chromedriver in python selenium to read the value.

all the tests gets me one of the intermediate values before it finishes loading.

I tried using the folling inplace of the browser2.implicitly_wait(5):

```
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser2,3)
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-magic-result')))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-magic-result')))
```

Here is the full code I am using

```
browser2 = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=driverPath)
url = 'https://www.junglescout.com/estimator/'
browser2.get(url)

container = browser2.find_element_by_class_name('js-estimation-section')
rankField = container.find_element_by_name('theRankInput')
rankField.send_keys('345')

# Click for storesList drop down
storeGroup = container.find_element_by_class_name('js-est-stores-list-input')
storeGroup.find_element_by_class_name('x-icon-caret-down').click()

# Get Stores List items
wait = WebDriverWait(browser2,3)
stores = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-est-stores-list')))
stores.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')[0].click()

# Wait for storesList is invisible
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-est-stores-list')))

# Click for Categories list drop down
catGroup = container.find_element_by_class_name('js-est-categories-list-input')
catGroup.find_element_by_tag_name('input').click()

# Get Categories List items
cats = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-est-categories-list')))

# Get Categories List items
for cat in cats.find_elements_by_class_name('us-available'):
    if (cat.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text == 'Electronics'):
        cat.click()
        break
# Wait for storesList is invisible
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-est-categories-list')))

# wait5 = WebDriverWait(browser2,3)
submit = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'js-est-btn')))
submit.click()

browser2.implicitly_wait(5)
print(container.find_element_by_class_name('js-magic-result').text)
```

What I expect is to get the final value returned but what I get is one of the intermediate values from the element.

Answer (score 2):

Instead Of

```
print(container.find_element_by_class_name('js-magic-result').text)
```

Please try this.

```
print(browser2.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='js-estimation-section']//tbody//tr/td[2]/p").text)
```

Make sure before print some delay should be there so please replace only print code.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, it's returning blank. I think it's returning right away before the result is returned. The problem, according to some debugging steps I took, seems to be that the implicit wait does not seem to work at all. No matter how long I make it wait, it returns right away. I tried 30 seconds and also 30000 (assuming if it is taking it as milliseconds).

Comment: I have tested on my laptop every time it’s returning some value 2450 like that.Don’t know why are you getting blank.I’ll check any further workaround.Thanks for your response.

Comment: That's actually the correct result. I included the line to see what it is getting using the code:
    'print(container.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='js-estimation-section']//tbody//tr/td[2]").get_attribute('innerHTML'))' and it's returning: 


    <p class="js-magic-result" style="display: none;">0</p>
    <div class="js-spinner" style="display: block; opacity: 0.0157084;">
    <div class="bounce1"></div>
    <div class="bounce2"></div>
<div class="bounce3"></div>
</div>
a

Comment: If you ```print(browser2.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='js-estimation-section']//tbody//tr/td[2]/p").text)```  what value are you getting?? please note that `browser2` not `container`

Comment: It's returning 0. I also changed the driver to firefox and same result.

Comment: Somehow I found a workaround. instead of the line `browser2.implicitly_wait(5)`, I replaced it with `time.sleep(2)` and that got me the right result. It seems to wait for the provided amount of seconds before reading the value. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Geat!!!!Can you please accept my answer by clicking accept button of my code message.if that helps you.